# Is there any framework or components that can scaffold complex types in EF Core/ASP.Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, scaffolding, ef-core-2.2

Using EF, I have quite a few types along the lines of:

```
public class Person
{
public int PersonID { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public virtual Address Address{ get; set; }
}   

public class Address
{
public int AddressID { get; set; }
public string FirstLine { get; set; }
public string SecondLine{ get; set; }
}
```

The scaffolding feature is great for building simple Controllers and views, but, I am forever modifying the defaults to add support for numerous complex types, or to support foreign keys.

At the moment, I have built myself something that basically causes a popup and does an AJAX type query, then populates a field. It works - but, it isn't good code and I'm not happy with it.

I've been searching for ages and I've turned a blank other than the old [MVCscaffolding project](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=mvcscaffolding) - I was wondering if there are any better scaffolding templates out there or frameworks that can assist with this as it is obviously a very common task and I can't believe I'm alone in needing a better solution here.

Comment: What do you specifically mean by *scaffolding*

Comment: Database First will auto generate the Entities for you. I guess you are doing Code First.

Comment: @TheGeneral - Sorry, I'll update to be clearer - I'm talking about Scaffolding "better" controllers/views... Back in the day, the MvcScaffolding project (https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=mvcscaffolding) helped and did a bit more than the built in templates, but, it is not core compatible and I can't find any replacement or other projects.

Comment: That Codeplex project has been moved to GitHub and updated to run with Visual Studio 2013+   https://github.com/processedbeets/ASP.NET-MVC-Scaffolding